# Отображение разных стрелочек в блоке в зависимости от элементов внутри при скролле

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть задача. У нас блок,  в нем  находиться 6 карточек, есть скролл в этом блоке, чтоб мы могли пролистывать карточки.
В самом начале у нас есть стрелка вправо, нужно:
-чтобы когда долистали до последнего элемента, эта стрелка скрылась и появилась слева(типа, листайте теперь только влево(в обратную сторону)

- когда долистываем обратно до самого первого элемента, стрелку слева убираем и ставим ее в правую сторону( типа, листайте теперь только вправо)
  Не могу придумать, как адекватно отследить появление 1-го и последнего элемента для скрытия/появление нужных стрелок
  И нюанс в том, что пока 1 и последнего элемента не видно, чтоб две стрелки были видны( одна в правую сторону, другая в левую)

Upd. Стрелки несут декоративную функцию, не являются кликабельнимы или кнопками переключения. Просто показывают в какую сторону можно скролить

Пример кода схематически с блоками и стрелками https://jsfiddle.net/7jthb24z/1/

HTML:

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class="arrow-left">
    arrow-left
  </div>
  <div class='child first'>
    text  first
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    text
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    text
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    text
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    text
  </div>
  <div class='child last'>
    text last
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-right">
    arrow-right
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 853px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 674px;
    height: auto;
    background: blue;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.arrow-left {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    background: yellow;
    width: 20px;
    height: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.arrow-right{
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    background: yellow;
    width: 20px;
    height: 15px;
    right: 50px;
    margin-top: 100px
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение такое. Вы должны повесить некий класс маркер, который будет отслеживать [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) при каждом нажатии на кнопки-стрелки. Если Вы на первом элементе из списка, то показываете `arrow-right` если на последнем элементе child.leight `arrow-left`. При каждом переходе, этот маркер удаляется из списка, а потом назначается на элемент текущего слайда.
Да, ещё желательно вынести элементы навигации слайдера за приделы блока слайдера.

Ну или воспользуйтесь готовыми библиотеками по типу [swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/demos) или [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: ооо Спасибо. если сами стрелки не кликабельны(не кнопки), просто как декорации, которые показывают куда можно листать?

Comment: не понял вопроса.  Кнопки лучше сменить на правильный тег `<button type="button">` если они не видимы, то им можно например присваивать атрибут `hidden`

Comment: по факту стрелки вправо/влево не являются кнопками(не переключают, не кликают), они только для декорации(показывают направления куда можно ганять элементы в блоке), по факту скрол происходит не как у слайдера, а просто из-за overflow-x: scroll,

Comment: по факту, я не знаю как вычислить, что элемент показался в пределах родительского блока, и потом уже скрывать или показывать декоративные стрелки. Видела код там где можно отследить когда элемент показывается в пределах window, когда человек просто скролит страницу. А вот в пределах моего блока, не могу выцепить

Comment: это не тривиальная задача, отслеживание по скроллу... это надо седеть разбираться. Тут или ищите уже готовое решение или оплатите и вам сделают. В любом случаи это уже выходит за приделы поставленного вопроса.

Comment: в любом случае спасибо, за то, что пытались помочь

Comment: Можно через JavaScript отслеживать положение элементов и решать, прокрутил ли пользователь достаточно до конца, чтобы скрыть стрелку, или же нет. Ну и повесить это дело на `onscroll`.